Docker container not recieving packets from specific port
So I have an instance in Oracle cloud, running OL7. In that instance I'm trying to setup some docker containers with multiple servers. These container should be reachable from the outside on different public IP addresses. Such that any request on port X and IP X.X.X.X would be forwarded to container A and same for all the subsequent containers.
In my instance I have one VNIC with a certain private IP address to which i bind the docker container. Supposedly when booting up the container all the rules and routes are setup properly and it does work for the 1st VNIC. However when I try to setup a second VNIC, the packets seem to not be sent to the container. They reach the instance but they aren't being sent to the container. Which makes no sense to me since all the rules and routes are similar to the 1st VNIC only with the different IPs/Subnets. And the most annoying thing is that the container can actually reach the internet, so it seems like it's specific to a port or server that I'm running.
I've published all of the relevant configuration files on my github https://github.com/6135/ServerFiles as they are quite large and I don't think i should post them outright. Any help would be appreciated, been struggling with this for a few days already.
